# Kafka Synchronous Producer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I come across the following like about synchronous send from the producer. I am aware of asynchronous mechanism in the context producer

> Invoking get() on this future will block until the associated request
> completes and then return the metadata for the record or throw any
> exception that occurred while sending the record.

What is really mean by *the associated request complete* , I am quite this is not referring to the *complete request* , but to what extent this phrase is referring ? till the broker ? till the buffer used in the producer etc .. ?

How it is different when ack = all is used along with synchronous producer and async producer ? Both scenarios are blocked for acknowledgment ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The producer has an internal queue to buffer some records (based on the configurations `linger.ms` and `min.batch.size`). There is an internal background thread that requests to the broker (where the leader partition is located) to send the batched data. Depending on the configuration `max.connections.in.flight` the producer can have multiple request in parallel. This is meant by "associated request".

> How it is different when ack = all is used along with synchronous producer and async producer ? Both scenarios are blocked for acknowledgment ?

The `get` method will block until the request to the broker is completed, meaning it received all acknowledgments based on the acks setting.

Using the `get` method always leads to a synchronous producer.

Comment: Thanks for insights, very helpful . what is the behavior if acks=all is used _without_ get method(async), will the producer still be blocked in terms of foreground thread or internal background thread as the leader need to wait for the acks from ISRs

Comment: If acks=all, the async producer will receive the responses of the replicas in the callback. However, your code is not blocked.